# No Background After Reboot

Tags: boot

I Changed My Background With Image Of My Choice And When I Shut Down The Pc And Start It Again The Wallpaper Is Blank And I Have To Set That "My Image" As Background Again And Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think everytime you are selecting the photo from folder/directory in the partition other than in which ubuntu is installed. So these partitions have to be first mounted after starting the system.I suggest you should move your photos to a directory in your pictures in /home or anywhere else in /home.

Comment: Cool It Works I Moved That Pic In "Pictures" Folder Of Home Drive And Now Its Showing In Every Boot I Dont Have To Set It Again And Again Previously It Is In NTFS Drive Of Data Storage

Thanx Thanx Thanx